# when upgrading to django 1.4 I get 'X' has a relation with model 'Y', which has either not been installed or is abstract

Tags: django, django-models

I am updrading from django 1.3.1 which had no prolems, adter the upgrade to 1.4

I get this error message :

exome_project.phen_form_choice: 'term' has a relation with model "class 'exome_project.models.Term'", which has either not been installed or is abstract.

The strange thing is that the Term class that is supposedly abstract or missing is
defined right above it in the same python file :

```
class Term(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    is_obsolete = models.IntegerField()
    is_root = models.IntegerField()
    subontology = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    acc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, Sub: %s' % (self.name, self.subontology)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'v_term'
        ordering = ['name','id']
        app_label = 'HPO Views'

class phen_form_choice(models.Model):
    term =  models.OneToOneField(Term, primary_key=True)
    phen_form_cat = models.ForeignKey('phen_form_category')
    display_order = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        #return u'Term Id: %s, Term Name: %s, Display Order: %s' % (self.term.name, self.phen_form_cat, self.display_order)
        return self.term.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['phen_form_cat','display_order']
```

Comment: Just to learn something: why sometimes the FK is a classname (e.g `Term`) but sometimes it's a string (e.g `'phen_form_category'`)?

Comment: don't know, I haven't written the code...

Answer (score 0):

I think (not sure) it could be because of the `app_label` attribute in the Term class.
If both classes are in the same models.py file (it seems to be), you could try to remove the `app_label = 'HPO Views'` line. Or if both file are not in models.py, add this line to the other class.

Then use syncdb command. If it still doesn't work and you have a dev environement, try to tally delete de database then rebuild it with syncdb.

about app-label: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label